# Is there a way for typescript to infer the value of a generic's variable type when used in a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Basically I would like to find a way for this to work:

```
type <T extends number | string>WithGeneric = T

function usesWithGeneric(arg: WithGeneric) { return arg } // I don’t want to provide T here

const number = usesWithGeneric(2) // works and of type number
const text = usesWithGeneric("haha") // works and is identified as a string
```

- This is a dumbed down version of my problem. I wouldn't do it for just `string | number`
- I don't want to write `function usesWithGeneric<T>(arg: WithGeneric<T>) {}`. I have way more complex generic types and redeclaring generic variables is a hassle
- I don't want to write `function usesWithGeneric(arg: WithGeneric<string | number>)  {}`. It breaks type safety.

[Here is a TS Playground if you want to test it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgcQgOwgJzgYwDwAqUEAHsOgCYDOUaArgLYBGWUAPlFcNmgOYB8UALxQCAKDEAzOmhzA4AezRQ6VCFXhJUGbDgAUAQ0y8AXLAQp0WXHnrNWHLjwEBKKAG8xUb1EwRgdJjKRrwA3GIAvhI4SlxQ5GRmTnB8wipqGhba1voARORcuS7hAPQlPj4AegD80bHAtIxmdiyYaarqmpY6uHoAzMViZRXeNUA)

---

**Update 23/03:** I now encountered a typical example of what bugs me

I'm working with urql and trying to implement a wrapper on the client

```js
const queryFactory = 
  (document, field?: any) =>
  (params: TParams) =>
    urqlClient
      .query(document, params)
      .toPromise()
      .then((res) => (field ? res.data?.[field] : res.data));
```

So I seem to have to declare the following (which doesn't work btw)

```js
import { TypedDocumentNode } from "urql";

export function query<
  TParams extends { [prop: string]: any },
  TResult,
  TDocument extends TypedDocumentNode<TResult, TParams>
>(document: TDocument): (params: TParams) => Promise<TResult | undefined>;

export function query<
  TParams extends { [prop: string]: any },
  TResult,
  TField extends keyof TResult,
  TDocument extends TypedDocumentNode<TResult, TParams>
>(document: TDocument, field: TField): (params: TParams) => Promise<TResult[TField] | undefined>;

export function query<
  TParams extends { [prop: string]: any },
  TResult,
  TField extends keyof TResult,
  TDocument extends TypedDocumentNode<TResult, TParams>
>(document: TDocument, field?: TField) {
  return (params: TParams) =>
    urqlClient
      .query(document, params)
      .toPromise()
      .then((res) => (field ? res.data?.[field] : res.data));
}
```

And I find that way too hard as I have to:

- Look at urql's query typings
- Try to replicate them to properly type my wrapper
- I always mess up at this point

Am I getting into this the wrong way ? I want to type as little typing as possible for a wrapper method like my factory

Comment: What do you mean by "I don’t want to provide T here" on the function declaration?

Answer (score 1):

> I have way more complex generic types and redeclaring generic variables is a hassle

It sounds like you want to be able to create more than one of these functions without having to repeat the generic bits. If so, you can do that by defining a generic function type:

```typescript
type FunctionWithGeneric = <T extends number | string>(arg: T) => T;
```

...then using it on the function(s) you want to create:

```typescript
const usesWithGeneric: FunctionWithGeneric = (arg) => {
    return arg;
};
```

Both of your assignments then work.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEHVXABYDiECEATqklALxQA8AKlBAB7DEAmAzlAnALYAjMlAA+UTsHIIA5gD4AFAENS0gFxR6ASmqyNAbgBQBpJglQ4nCJxz4iJcknXxkaTDcLEyFalCUrtVLoA3gZQYVCkEMBwpAhQytKGAL6GxqbAUGys6hJS0j4WVu52XkjyAERsEuWahgD0deHhAHoA-EYmCGa8fOo9QqQFlta4HvYU8gDMtQYNTWFtQA)

Comment: We can probably even generalize this to handle functions that need to have other parameters if needed, but I'll hold off until/unless I know I'm solving the right problem. :-)

Comment: It's a good solution but not sure if it fits my needs, I need to come up with a more complicated TS Playground to illustrate this

Comment: @Ginko - Okay, ping me when you do and I'll try to help. :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder - I finally encountered I more complex example which I just added to the description